# Calculate GLSL shader cost

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a list of different shaders, that calculate on vertex and Pixel shaders. And i need calculate how many instructions(cycles) in this shader, for vertex and pixel . I understand that shader execution time depend not only from shader complexity. 
In ARM documentation(http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0555c/BEIHGICG.html and http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0555c/BABDDGHC.html)  i found how it can be calculated on Mali GPU's: malisc -v my_shader.frag. But i use not Mali GPU's, do you have any ideas how i can do it?

Target platform Windows 7 x64
GPU adapter Nvidia with CUDA
SDK VS 2010

Comment: Just curious, but why would you even want to do/calculate that?

Comment: this can show how many frames we can get in Ideal World, after that i can compare Ideal result with current result, and found difference in percentage, and approximately can chose better shader that can give required FPS

Comment: But why not simply benchmark your Shaders and then pick the one's which are best and give the fastest execution time?

Comment: because shader can be written on client side

Comment: If the shader is sufficiently complex (eg loops, places to optimize maths at runtime etc), there's no way of knowing its cost. How long is a piece of string? How long will a program take to run? You may do some complexity analysis and have a guess but in my experience results will just vary too much. Benchmarking, dynamic learning or some hand coded weighting for choosing is the way.

Comment: In Program we have some limitation on shader, shader could not use loop, if and switch operators. Shader string can be several kb length.

Comment: Might https://developer.nvidia.com/nvemulate be useful? (I haven't tried it myself)

Comment: GuyRT - thanks for program it very useful, but mainly that not show instruction for Shader ((

Comment: This is pretty much impossible. The number of cycles taken depends on the Instruction Set Architecture, and each GPU generation tends to define an entirely new one. You would have to compile this shader multiple times (for each GPU generation) and then trace the disassembly. This is not to say there are not tools that do this, but the results will be extremely hardware specific. Different models have different VRAM configurations and a tex fetch may be considerably more expensive even though the ISA is the same, it is a nightmare to do low-level stuff on anything but fixed-spec. systems.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman, I also think about this way ((. "multiple times (for each GPU generation)" - you mean several times for every GPU's, or for every GPU's only one times? i think do it automatically on client side, for theirs specific HW

Comment: This would not be something you do with OpenGL itself, actually. The tools that do this are actually offline. They will compile the GLSL shader for you, then analyze them without running them through the OpenGL pipeline. But the point I was getting at is that the number of cycles taken for memory fetches, etc. varies not only by GPU generation, but also between different models of the same GPU (e.g. a Radeon HD 7970 has a 384-bit wide GDDR5 memory interface, but a 7510 has a 128-bit wide DDR3 interface) even though they have the same shader architecture.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman - It is interesting software that you describe, could you give it name?

Comment: @AndriyMytroshyn: I am most familiar with AMD's [GPUShaderAnalyzer](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzer/#), it has a [nice GUI](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GSA.png) that displays disassembly and general cycle information (the screenshot shows HLSL, but it works for GLSL too). NVIDIA also has a similar command-line tool called [ShaderPerf](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvshaderperf_home.html).

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman, this program good, but it old, for example ShaderPerf compiled Jun 11 2008. GPU shader Analyzer that i used compiled in 2012, this data also not correctly, becausw maximal gpu series it is 6***.